# Which external lights are present on a unmodified Cessna P210N?

Tags: datasets, aircraft-external-lights, cessna-210-centurion

What external lights are present on a unmodified Cessna P210N "Pressurized Centurion", and where are they placed ? I've looked through the POH and searched on Google for e.g. "cessna P210N external lights", or "lights", or …, but I could not find the information anywhere, and sadly I don't have an airfield nearby where I could look at a real one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies from year to year or A/C to A/C depending on factory options, STCs, etc.  Typically the P210’s exterior lights consisted of:

- Red/Green/White navigation lights in the wingtips and tail.
- Red omnidirectional anticollision beacon on top of vertical fin.
- L/R wingtip white strobe lights.
- Underwing mounted courtesy lights.
- Cowl mounted landing and taxi lights.

See this [P210N POH](http://www.marksetcetera.com/N731PJ-P210N-POH.pdf), Section 6: Weight & Balance / Equipment List and Section 7: Airplane and Systems Description.